# What and where exactly is the loader?

Tags: c, linux, linker, system-calls, loader

I understand every bit of the C compilation process (how the object files are linked to create the executable). But about the loader itself (which starts the program running) I have a few doubts.

1. Is the loader part of the kernel?
2. How exactly is the `./firefox` or some command like that loaded? I mean you normally type such commands into the terminal which loads the executable I presume. So is the loader a component of the shell?

I think I'm also confused about where the terminal/shell fits into all of this and what its role is.

Comment: Q1: No; the loader is classically a regular program called `ld`; it is not part of the kernel.  It is also called a linker (but the name is still `ld`).  It collects object files and libraries and creates an executable from them — or creates a shared library if you invoke it with the correct options, and there are one or two other things that you can produce if you're knowledgeable enough.  Q2: Are you meaning how the Firefox is run, or how it is linked? Running the program is not a part of the compilation process, but is sometimes called 'loading the program'. And that code is in the kernel.

Comment: Q2 (cont): Well, some of the code is in the kernel; another major chunk is the dynamic loader, which often has a name such as `ld.so.1`.  We really need a bit more context for what you seek to know about.  The chances are, though, that the question is too broad for SO.

Comment: I think OP is talking about loading a process image not linking. But he may precise his question...

Comment: +Jonathan Leffler Thank you. I understand the linking process reasonably well . I was just trying to get some understanding of what goes on from the creation of the executable to the actual execution of the executable. And where the shell fits into all of this, if it actually does?

Comment: Nothing happens between the end of the executable being linked and it being executed — unless it gets copied (installed) somewhere new.  When you run the executable, whether that's from a shell command line or some other mechanism (such as clicking on an icon), then the kernel gets involved (via an `exec()` family system call — and usually `fork()` too), to get the program started.  Then the dynamic loader sorts out shared libraries, and the program starts running.  This is a big topic; you should find a text book and read up on what goes on in more detail.

Comment: I've tweaked the verbiage in your question to, I hope, clarify what you're asking about.  Check that what's there now accurately reflects your concerns.  Be cautious about using the term 'loader' because the linker is also called the loader — witness the name `ld` (which is fairly obviously an abbreviation of 'load').

Comment: +Jonathan Leffler Thats perfect. Thank you.

Comment: The [tag:C] tag isn't really relevant to the topic of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of an executable determines how it will be loaded. For example executables with "#!" as the first two characters are loaded by the kernel by executing the named interpreter and feeding the file to it as the first argument. If the executable is formatted as a PE, ELF, or MachO binary then the kernel uses an intrepter for that format that is built in to the kernel in order to find the executable code and data and then choose the next step.

In the case of a dynamically linked ELF, the next step is to execute the dynamic loader (usually ld.so) in order to find the libraries, load them, abd resolve the symbols. This all happens in userspace. The kernel is more or less unaware of dynamic linking, because it all happens in userspace after the kernel has handed control to the interprter named in the ELF file.

Answer (score 1):

The corresponding system call is `exec`. It is part of the kernel and in charge of cleaning the old address space that makes the call and get a new fresh one with all materials to run a new code. This is part of the kernel because address space is a kind of sandbox that protect processes from others, and since it is critical it is in charge of the kernel.

The shell is just in charge of interpreting what you type and transform it to proper structures (list or arrays of C-strings) to pass to some `exec` call (after having, most of the time, spawned a new process with `fork`).